# JBoss deployment overlay - nested deployments

Tags: deployment, jboss, overlay

i'm trying deployement-overlay in my JBoss EAP 6.3.3 with an ear file included war file.
after reading this article : https://access.redhat.com/solutions/383393, i did this CLI command : 
deployment-overlay add --name=eum_overlay --server-groups=SG_IHMS_APM --content=/spb-bo-voyage-2.0.0.war/template/template.xhtml=/tmp/template.xhtml --deployments=spb-voyage-2.0.0.ear --redeploy-affected but it doesn't work for me !

Have you got an idea ?

Thanks a lot

Ludo

Answer (score 1):

With RedHat support help i found a solution and i want to share it with you :

first : the war inside the ear should not be a zip file (sometimes war file are zipped), in this case it doesn't work !

now you have an ear file with war file inside (unpack mode) and you want use JBoss deployment overlay, use this command :

deployment-overlay add --name=Overlay_Name --content=/name_of_the_war_file.war/folder_inside_war/file.xxx=path_to_file_that_will_overlay_the_file.xxx --deployments=name_of_the_ear_file.ear --server-groups=server_group_name --redeploy-affected

it works very fine for me !

Good use !

Ludo

Comment: What do you mean by _the war inside the ear should not be a zip file_ ? My `app.ear` has a `web-app.war` inside it. Does that mean I have to explode the war inside the ear?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue with JBoss 6.4.18, seems like my internal war has to be exploded as a directory. Kind of annoying...

Answer (score 0):

For all the other poor souls that are still struggling with this in 2023, here's what I found working:

```
deployment-overlay add --name=my-nice-jar \
    --content=/nested-webapp.war/WEB-INF/lib/my-nice.jar=/path/to/my-nice.jar \
    --deployments=my-overlord-app.ear \
    --redeploy-affected
```

The key is to add `/nested-webapp.war/` in the `--content` parameter. I am using WildFly 27.0.1.Final.